# How to fix typings in typescript for Mongo update with $currentDate on optional property

Tags: mongodb, typescript

I am using `typescript v3.7.2`, `mongo v3.4.1` and `@types/mongodb 3.3.14`, and my goal is to use the [$currentDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) operator with typings. My problem is that it only works, if the property on the object in question is not optional.

Code:

```js
import { UpdateQuery } from 'mongodb';

interface Car {
  name: string;
  updatedDate?: Date;
}

const updateQuery: UpdateQuery<Car> {
  $currentDate: {
    updatedDate: true // <== this throws error when updatedDate is optional.
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
Types of property 'updatedDate' are incompatible.
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or are the typings wrong?

**Workaround**

Fixed by downgrading the types package `npm i @types/mongodb@3.3.5 --save-dev`